# se puede hacer que un button en java cambie de color automáticamente según el estado de una habitación?

Tags: java, netbeans

hola estoy trabajando en un software para un hotel en java netbeans y quiero mostrar mediante un jframe unos botones que me representen el estado de las habitaciones sin necesidad de que se le de clic al botón, si esta disponible verde, si esta ocupada rojo, si esta en mantenimiento azul, reserva amarilo. lo estoy haciendo primero solo con un botón a ver si me sale pero nada.
esta es mi consulta de SQL del estado de la habitación.

```
public String obtenerEstadoHabitacion(int idhabitacion) {

    String estado = "Disponible";

    try {
        sSQL = "SELECT estado FROM habitacion WHERE idhabitacion = ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        pst.setInt(0, idhabitacion);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            estado = rs.getString("estado");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      
        
    }

    return estado;
}
```

y jframe es este

```
package Presentacion;
```

````
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;```

`public class Jmenuhotel extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

    private final Fhabitacion colorhbt;

    public Jmenuhotel() {
        initComponents();
        setTitle("MENU HOTEL");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        colorhbt = new Fhabitacion();
        btn1 = new JButton("habitacion 1");
        String estado = colorhbt.obtenerEstadoHabitacion(1);
        setButtonColor(btn1, obtenerColorDisponibilidad(estado));

    }

    private Color obtenerColorDisponibilidad(String estado) {
        return switch (estado) {
            case "Disponible" ->
                Color.GREEN;
            case "Reservada" ->
                Color.YELLOW;
            case "Ocupada" ->
                Color.RED;
            case "Mantenimiento" ->
                Color.BLUE;
            default ->
                Color.RED;
        };
    }

    private void setButtonColor(JButton button, Color color) {
        button.setBackground(color);
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
````

Answer (score 0):

Se puede. Tus métodos `obtenerColorDisponibilidad` y `setButtonColor` funcionan correctamente. Lo único que no veo es cuando añades el botón dentro del JFrame principal ni cuando haces visible dicho JFrame.

Si ejecutas este código verás cómo el botón cambia dependiendo del estado al hacer click. He creado un método `cambiarColor` que obtiene un estado random y establece el valor de un JLabel (para poder ver el estado seleccionado) y que cambia el color del botón invocando a tus métodos. Lo último que hace ese método es llamar a un repaint del JFrame para que los cambios en JLabel y JButton se reflejen en la pantalla.

Nota: He comentado el case de "Ocupada" porque IntelliJ me avisaba de que era redundante, pues el rojo es el color por defecto.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestColoredButton extends JFrame {

    private static final List<String> LISTA_ESTADOS =
            List.of("Disponible", "Reservada", "Ocupada", "Mantenimiento", "Otro");

    public TestColoredButton() {
        setTitle("MENU HOTEL");
        setSize(400, 400);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Cambiar color!");
        button.addActionListener(event -> cambiarColor(label, button));

        cambiarColor(label, button);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void cambiarColor(JLabel label, JButton button) {
        String randomEstado = getRandomEstado();
        label.setText(randomEstado);
        Color color = obtenerColorDisponibilidad(randomEstado);
        setButtonColor(button, color);

        repaint();
    }

    private String getRandomEstado() {
        return LISTA_ESTADOS.get(new Random().nextInt(LISTA_ESTADOS.size()));
    }

    private Color obtenerColorDisponibilidad(String estado) {
        return switch (estado) {
            case "Disponible" ->    Color.GREEN;
            case "Reservada" ->     Color.YELLOW;
            //case "Ocupada" ->       Color.RED;
            case "Mantenimiento" -> Color.BLUE;
            default ->              Color.RED;
        };
    }

    private void setButtonColor(JButton button, Color color) {
        button.setBackground(color);
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestColoredButton();
    }
}
```